# How can i sum a value based on a Alias ? Or sum a Column which is already being summed?

Tags: sql, sum

Here is the query that i 'm struggling with.

```
PRJ_C  AS Project,
UDF as SupplyPeriod
Round( SUM (Cost.Total),2)  as TotalCost 
FROM R5PRO
WHERE PRJ_C IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY PRJ_C, UDF
```

Here Cost is a table from where i 'm fetching all the costs based on projects. e.x

**Project      TotalCost      SupplyPeriod
ABC            1234           SP1
DEF            5678           SP2

i want to sum all the cost based on Supply Period.
Can you please guide me how can i do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ROLLUP or CUBE functions depending on which database system you are using.

```
select 
PRJ_C  AS Project,
UDF as SupplyPeriod
Round( SUM (Cost.Total),2)  as TotalCost 
FROM R5PRO
WHERE PRJ_C IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(PRJ_C, UDF);
```

or

```
select 
PRJ_C  AS Project,
UDF as SupplyPeriod
Round( SUM (Cost.Total),2)  as TotalCost 
FROM R5PRO
WHERE PRJ_C IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY CUBE(PRJ_C, UDF);
```

or if you want only single output row you can use

```
with temp_tab as(
select 
PRJ_C  AS Project,
UDF as SupplyPeriod
Round( SUM (Cost.Total),2)  as TotalCost 
FROM R5PRO
WHERE PRJ_C IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY PRJ_C, UDF)
select sum(TotalCost) from temp_tab;
```

Comment: ROLLUP and CUBE functions are similar, but selection of which function you should use depends on which subselection you want to get from your groups.